# Jetpack Compose view position and shadow preview is different to on when running on device

Tags: position, android-jetpack-compose, android-virtual-device, shadow, preview

I have the below code, however the Preview is rendering the view different to when I run it on a AVD (Android Virtual Device).  It looks there are 2 things different:

Firstly, the AVD is rending the view at the top of the screen, but the preview is rending the view in the centre of the screen.  I've added `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` to my `AlertView` `Box` which I believe should render it in the middle of the screen.

Secondly, the AVD is showing a weird shadow compared to the preview.

Images below of the preview and AVD:

[image: Preview]
[image: AVD]

```
//Preview Provider
@Preview(
    showSystemUi = true,
    device = Devices.PIXEL_4_XL,
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO,
    showBackground = true,
    backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF
)
@Preview(
    showSystemUi = true,
    device = Devices.PIXEL_4,
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
    showBackground = true,
    backgroundColor = 0xFF000000
)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AlertView()
}



//AlertViewModel
class AlertViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var showAlert: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)
    var alertIcon: ImageVector by mutableStateOf(Icons.Rounded.WifiOff)
    var alertTitle: String by mutableStateOf("No internet connection")
    var alertMessage: String by mutableStateOf("This is the alert message and it is purposely longer than one line to be displayed on screen")
    var alertButtonText: String by mutableStateOf("This is the alert button text")
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//.onCreate
class AlertManager : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AlertView()
        }
    }
}



//AlertView
@Composable
fun AlertView(alertViewModel: AlertViewModel = viewModel()) {

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(30.dp, 0.dp)
                .background(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                    color =
                    if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.Black
                    } else {
                        Color.White
                    }
                )
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 1.dp,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                    ambientColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.Black
                    } else {
                        Color.White
                    },
                    spotColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.White
                    } else {
                        Color.Gray
                    },
                )
                .padding(30.dp, 25.dp),
        ) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = alertViewModel.alertIcon,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.White
                    } else {
                        Color.Black
                    },
                )


                Text(
                    text = alertViewModel.alertTitle,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                            Color.White
                        } else {
                            Color.Black
                        }
                    )
                )
            }

            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(25.dp),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = alertViewModel.alertMessage,
                    color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                        Color.White
                    } else {
                        Color.Black
                    }
                )

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        alertViewModel.showAlert = false
                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        backgroundColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                            Color.White
                        } else {
                            Color.Black
                        }
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(15.dp),
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = alertViewModel.alertButtonText,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                            Color.Black
                        } else {
                            Color.White
                        }
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```